# How to update rows in Jooq without Codegen using JSON

Tags: jooq

I am using Jooq version 3.17.0 and attempting to insert data into a table without codegen.
At the minute, I am designing a system that allows data to be imported into multiple tables (one at a time, and starting with just one), yet I do not want to write specific code for each table and as of now, I haven't had a need for codegen.

The code currently works for importing data via JSON, with json being a String formatted in the 'Jooq' format. This imports data correctly into the database. This also allows us to send json data of table updates from one system to our main system that uses Jooq. Yet it gives me an error when I try to update.

I am using MYSQL as my database.

The original code for insertion is :

```
Result<Record> convertedJson = dslContext.fetchFromJSON(json);
Loader<Record> res1 = dslContext.loadInto(table(tableName)).loadJSON(json).fields(convertedJson.fields()).execute();
```

However, if we try to update data by sending in the same json, but with one field changed, jooq gives an error `org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException` stating that there is a duplicate entry for key.

I tried to use :

```
Loader<Record> res2 = dslContext.loadInto(table(tableName)).onDuplicateKeyUpdate().loadJSON(json).fields(convertedJson.fields()).execute();
```

But then this throws an error `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE only works on tables with explicit primary keys. Table is not updatable : <tableName>` since in LoaderImpl.onDuplicateKeyUpdate():220 since table.getPrimaryKey() is null which technically makes sense since table(tableName) returns a Table that does not know it's fields.

My question is probably two-fold.

1. Is there a way to have a table that is aware of it's fields without codegen?
2. Is there a way for me to allow jooq to update rows this way.

My preferences is to steer clear of codegen, unless it's really needed. I probably could switch to codegen if needed, but again I would still need to be able to execute SQL without writing specific code for each table. Using JSON is still very much desired, as that allows me to send data from one application to another for import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using code generation

You've run into [one of those many reasons why code generation is very helpful with jOOQ](https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/). If your various tables are known at compile time, and all you're doing is switch table names, then I would go with generated code, making the lookup of the table dynamic. That would solve the problem easily.

From experience with various similar support cases, I've always recommended this first, because as soon as these kinds of troubles start, it's a good idea to re-think the code generation strategy as you will run into other, similar problems, having to work around the lack of ubiquitously available meta data all the time. There are many other benefits to using the code generator.

#### Emulating code generation

If for some reason you cannot (e.g. the tables aren't known at compile time) or do not want to use the code generator, then you can do the code generator's work yourself at runtime, by [building `CustomTable` types as documented here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-queryparts/).

#### Using other means of providing meta information

Another way to provide jOOQ with meta data is to use [one of various forms of implementing `org.jooq.Meta`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/meta-data/), which include:

- [Looking up meta data from the JDBC driver's `DatabaseMetaData`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/meta-data/meta-jdbc/) (this can be slow, depending on your schema)
- [Letting jOOQ interpret some DDL scripts](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/meta-data/meta-interpreter/)
- [Using jOOQ's XML representation of the standard SQL `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/meta-data/meta-xml/)
- [Using generated code](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/meta-data/meta-generated/)

Comment: Thank you Lukas for the detailed response, it's great to see how responsive you are and is one of the reasons why I was so keen on using Jooq, even if I was missing out on some of the best features such as codegen!

Comment: Accidentally hit enter too soon.

I tried your suggestion for DatabaseMetaData and it works for me. I don't think my schema will be massive, probably less than 100 tables and I do not see much complexity in individual tables. Is there something that I need to keep in mind based on your comment about it being slow?
If more issues arise, I will probably heed your warning and switch to codegen.

Comment: @java_stack_account_bd: Well, every time you have a cache miss in your `Meta` object, jOOQ (via JDBC) will run several queries to fetch meta data that you probably already know at compile time. It's likely you're making the wrong tradeoff here. But then again, indeed, you can switch later, as the various `Meta` implementations are interchangeable. [You can even have one purely based on generated code](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/meta-data/meta-generated/)